# Testing livewire component does not transfer variable to route() method

Tags: laravel-livewire

I'm testing my livewire component. In my component view I have a named route

```
route('add_result_bulk', ['round' => $round])
```

When I run the test, it gives this error:

```
Missing required parameter for [Route: add_results_bulk] [URI: results/add/{round}/bulk] [Missing parameter: round]. (View: /var/www/resources/views/results/livewire/add-results.blade.php) (View: /var/www/resources/views/results/livewire/add-results.blade.php)
```

If I put a `@dd($round)` right in front of the `route()` call, it dumps the `$round` variable.

Why is it not picking it up in the route then? My route is defined as:

```
Route::get('results/add/{round}/bulk', [ResultsController::class, 'bulk'])->name('add_results_bulk');
```

This is my test:

```
Livewire::test(AddResultsWrapper::class, ['round' => $round])
    ->set('results', [
        [
            "id" => null,
            "name" => "",
            "reserve" => null,
            "clean" => false,
        ], [
            "id" => null,
            "name" => "Driver 2",
            "reserve" => null,
            "clean" => false,
        ],
    ])->call('validate')
    ->assertHasErrors(['results.0.name']);
}
```

`$round` is declared as a public property in my component. When I access the page through the browser, the link shows up and works correctly.

This is my view:

```
<div>
    <form wire:submit.prevent="">
        @csrf
        <input type="hidden" name="form_type" value="single">
        <div class="max-w-7xl mx-auto py-10">
            <div class="bg-white overflow-hidden shadow-xl xl:rounded-lg overflow-x-auto">
                <div class="p-6 pb-0 px-8 bg-white grid grid-cols-12 gap-x-4 gap-y-1 form-container min-w-1200px">
                    <div class="col-span-12">
                        <b>Please note:</b> When adding multi-lobby results, results need to be added using the <a
                            href="{{ route('add_results_bulk', ['round' => $round]) }}"
                            class="no-underline hover:underline text-blue-700">Bulk Loader</a>. Loading the results
                        here, will cause positions to be calculated incorrectly.
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div
                    class="p-6 px-8 bg-white border-b border-gray-200 grid grid-cols-12 gap-x-4 gap-y-1 form-container min-w-1200px">
...
```